# Кнопка "Оставить комментарий"

Tags: html, вконтакте

Здравствуйте. Видел на сайтах кнопку "Оставить комментарий" от Контакта. Так вот, не могу найти html код.

Answer (score 2):

Документация: [Виджет для комментариев](https://vk.com/dev/Comments)